# Oracle APEX refresh an IFrame from the URL in a field of a IG

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have and Interactive Grid (IG) that has a field that contains an URL that i want to use to load in an IFRAME in the same page.

I want to refresh that iframe when users click on the diferent rows of the IG.

Is there any way to get that?

I can get the selected row with this and how i reference the URL column? by it's position?
selectedRecord = this.data.selectedRecords[0][0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dynamic action` with the row selected (IG) and as an action, execute Javascript code:

```
var widget = apex.region(igID).widget();
var grid = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews', 'grid');
var model = grid.model;
model.forEach(function (r) {
    var record = r;
    model.setValue(record, 'YOURCOLUMNNAME', 'the value you want to set');
});
```

This will itarate over your rows in the IG and set the value to specific column of each row.

Comment: Thanks! wasn't exactly what i was looking for but it was better cause gives me more options!!! great and fast answer! I cannot vote your answer for reputacion but have marked it as valid.